# Importance of openGL?

Tags: opengl

How important is it to learn openGL when using game enginges such as Unity, cocos2d-x, lib-GDX and generally in game developing? Can you still create very complex, high-quality games without knowing openGL?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are using a game engine like Unity, or cocos2d-x , game maker(...) you don't *need* to learn Opengl(or any other graphics API, really) but it can be *useful*. "Can you still create very complex, high-quality games without knowing openGL?" Short answer: Yes, you can. Long answer: Making an high quality game, (as long as you use a game engine) doesn't require you to know a graphics Api at all. Making an high quality game requires all sorts of skills other than programming. Art, sound design, level design, ui design are just a few of the many things that make an high quality AAA title nowdays.